# How do I create a LiveUSB for mac without os x?

Tags: boot, live-usb, mac

I have a white macbook (2007) which doesn't have os x installed on it, it only boots up using the recovery drive. Is there a way to create a bootable usb which I can use to install Ubuntu on my mac. I only have access to a windows computer (can't install anything on my mac, obviously) and a 16 gb flash drive.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to follow these instructions to install this software and create a bootable USB stick so that you can use that to start and install Ubuntu on your other computer: [How to create a bootable USB 
stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

You can get the ISO which you will need to install on the USB stick from here: [Download Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Then you will need to insert the USB stick into your other computer which you wish to install Ubuntu on and then turn it on so that it boots from the stick. Then you can proceed with the installation. 
If it does not boot off the USB stick then you will need to move that device to the top of the machine's Boot Order in the machine's EFI settings. To access the EFI settings on a Mac, follow these instructions: [How to get into the macbook bios](http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_7683617_macbook-bios.html)

Comment: So any Ubuntu live iso (usb/dvd) will work on a mac? Don't need anything special done to it?

Comment: @Xen2050: Yes, you shouldn't need anything special.

Comment: Although I haven't tried the burning the ISO file on a DVD and then trying to boot up. Will get back to you in a few days after I get hold of an empty dvd.

Comment: @Nash890: Ok, I have added some more information to my answer to tell you how to get into your EFI settings on your Mac (EFI is the Mac equivalent to BIOS).

Comment: This is more or less a link only answer, nor does the EFI link tell you how to get the "bootable" USB stick to boot, when there is no OSX installation present. If there isn't an OSX installation present, then there is no EFI boot option offered, when booting while holding the Option key down. The EFI boot option is required as it is the *only* way to get the Ubuntu USB stick to boot.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't replaced the Data Cable for the Hard Drive in your Mac. I would start there.
I spent hours, days, and weeks working around similar issues, used three different drives. The odd thing was I could boot using external drives, but I could not move any of those drives to the internal bay... The Mac would not detect them. As soon as I purchased a data cable replacement I was up in a half hour. Yes you still may need a startup disk, but addressing the real issue may save more time.
Best of Luck!

Comment: The recovery drive that boots may be a partition of the internal working hard drive, so the drive itself may be working (at least the recovery partition)

Comment: Yup. The drive itself is working. When installing os x a recovery partition is created incase something goes wrong.